# element.sortable is not a function Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, spring, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use ui.sortable to create a sortable list. I followed https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable but i still can't get it to work and get this error message TypeError: element.sortable is not a function. i load jquery and jquery-ui using:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

but still no luck. Im using angularJS + Spring boot system: https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research, i found that the application utilises Wro4j which require to import webjars through wro.xml file. So if the JS dependancy in this case jquery-ui, exists as a webjar you would be able to add it to the application. worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

You need to register ui.sortable in the $scope.
Eg: if the function is called as elementSort()

```js
function mainController ($scope, $http){
    $scope.elementSort =  function(data){
    console.log(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: dont really understand what you mean

Comment: you get a TypeError in angularJS + Spring boot system not because of just the way you load jquery library. To use ui.sortable the function that you are using needs to be registered the way I have shown above in $scope.

Comment: Please give more explanations.. What function are you talking about? Where should this code go? Why would he need to do this?